# Wildfly 10 per-deployment Logging

Tags: java, log4j, java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

I need to configure Hybernate logging for WildFly 10 to be used with Arquillian integration tests. I'd rather keep the server configuration to its default, if possible.  [The documentation says](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-PerdeploymentLogging),

> Per-deployment Logging
>
> Per-deployment logging allows you to add a logging configuration file
>   to your deployment and have the logging for that deployment configured
>   according to the configuration file. In an EAR the configuration
>   should be in the META-INF directory. In a WAR or JAR deployment the
>   configuration file can be in either the META-INF or WEB-INF/classes
>   directories.
>
> The following configuration files are allowed:
>
> ```
> logging.properties
> jboss-logging.properties
> log4j.properties
> log4j.xml
> jboss-log4j.xml
> ```

And so I've got my basic logging.properties file under META-INF in the ShrinkWrap JAR (there's no trace of hibernate options, of course, as I've stripped it down to the bare minimum):

```
log=<existing directory>

log4j.rootLogger = FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/myapp.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

The problem is, that neither myapp.log is created nor any error messages visible in server.log nor in Gradle build output. There are no problems with file permissions, double-checked. The `/META-INF/logging.properties` file shows up nicely in stringified ShrinkWrap JAR in build output.

Apparently, I'm missing some very basic things everyone else knows. Still, could someone help me out?

EDIT:

The ShrinkWrap archive as per toString(true):

```
... Some other application classes ...
/com/example/package/LocalDateAttributeConverter.class
/com/example/package/LocalTimeAttributeConverter.class
/com/example/package/LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class
/com/example/package/LocaleConverter.class
/META-INF/
/META-INF/persistence.xml
/META-INF/sql/
/META-INF/sql/drop.sql
/META-INF/beans.xml
/META-INF/logging.properties
```

Comment: If you are creating a war, can you try either put the file in WEB-INF/classes and ifnot in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF ?

Comment: @lordofthejars: no, it's just a set of JPA entity classes and integration tests, so there's no WEB-INF at all.

Comment: Is it possible you paste in gist the result of the ShrinkWrap archive? Just use archive.toString(true)

Comment: FWIW Hibernate will always use the system default configuration and never a deployments logging configuration. That said say you're using a `logging.properties`, but the configuration file looks like a log4j.properties. Which are you using?

Comment: @lordofthejars: done.